# Batch file format specifier

Tags: batch-file

I need to loop through all .c files in a directory using a batch file, so I did:

```
for %%f in (*.c) do (
```

But I don't want the file main.c to be included in this. Is there a way to go:

```
for %%f in (*.c apart from main.c) do (
```

UPDATE: What is the correct format for this?

```
for %%f in (*.c) do (
if %%~nf==main goto nope

; do stuff here

:nope
)
```

I just get ") was unexpected at this time."

Comment: Any `goto` inside a `for`statement breakes your loop - even if the target is inside the loop. So effectively `:nope` is logically outside the loop - and therefore `)` gives an error. There are already two valid answers to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `if` for this inside `for` loop

EDIT:

```
for %%f in (*.c) do if "%%f" NEQ "main.c" echo %%f
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b /od *.c^|findstr /i /v "main.c"') do echo %%a
```